# AppSettings.config - split a string into the list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a string in appsettings.json:

```
    {
  "GeneralSettings": {
    "CompanyIds": "1,2,3,4,5"
  }
}
```

How can I map it to a class, I need split it into the list by comma:

```
public class GeneralSettings
{
    public List<int> CompanyIds { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have:

```
var generalSettings = new GeneralSettings();  
configuration.GetSection(nameof(GeneralSettings)).Bind(generalSettings);
```

Comment: Why is it a string, and not an array? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61203218/asp-net-core-custom-converter-appsettings-json-for-idictionarystring-object if you must parse it yourself, then do so.

Comment: a good idea!! Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just have an array in your config file ?

```
{
  "GeneralSettings": {
    "CompanyIds": [1,2,3,4,5]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code :

```
 var generalSettings = new GeneralSettings(); 
 var values = _configuration.GetSection(nameof(GeneralSettings) +   ":CompanyIds").Value;
 generalSettings.CompanyIds  = values.Split(",").ToList().ConvertAll(int.Parse);
```

or

```
generalSettings.CompanyIds =  values.Split(",").Select(c=>int.Parse(c)).ToList();
```